# C++: Storing structs in a stack

Tags: c++, struct, stack

I have a struct:

```
    struct Vehicle
{
    char ad; // Arrival departure char
    string license; // license value
    int arrival; // arrival in military time
};
```

I want to store all the values in the struct in a stack.

I can store one value in the stack by doing:

```
    stack<string> stack; // STL Stack object
    Vehicle v; //vehicle struct object
    stack.push(v.license);
```

How can I store a the whole struct in the stack so I can later access the char, int, and, string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple, just replace `string` for `Vehicle` and an instance of `string` for an instance of `Vehicle`:

```
stack< Vehicle > stack; // STL Stack object
Vehicle v; //vehicle struct object
stack.push(v);
```

Comment: Haha, I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The type between the `<` and `>` is what your stack will hold. The first one held `string`s, you can have one that holds `Vehicles`:

```
std::stack<Vehicle> stack;
Vehicle v;
stack.push(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

What would happen when v goes out of scope? I guess you'd better created object on the heap and stores pointers to them in your stack:

```
void Foo(Stack <Vehicle>& stack) {
  Vehicle* vPtr = new Vehicle();
  stack.push(vPtr);
}
```

Comment: can I just do stack.push({new Vehicle()})?

Comment: I like your syntax since it specifies that you don’t intend to use explicit pointers to a newly created object.