# C++ Who storing the struct in the stack (STL)

Tags: c++, struct, stl, stack

I have a Problem like this: 
[C++: Storing structs in a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126955/c-storing-structs-in-a-stack/29655319#29655319)

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct adresse{

    string info;
};

int main(){

    string eingabe;
    stack<adresse> Stack1;

    cout << "Bitte Ausdruck eingeben: " << endl;
    getline( cin, eingabe);

    adresse* temp;
    temp = new adresse;
    temp->info = eingabe[0];
    Stack1.push(temp);

    return 0;  
}
```

The error is:

```
reference to type 'const value_type'(aka 'const adresse') could not bind to an 
lvalue of type 'adresse *'Stack1.push(temp);
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Tommy

Comment: You're trying to push a pointer onto your stack and it doesn't accept pointers.

Comment: Some hints: Always pair a new with a delete (or delegate to a smart pointer), never store pointers in a container (unless you need polymorphism ), do not fool around and get informed. (BTW: your German is awful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems.

First your header `<stdio.h>` is a `C` header, in `C++` use `<cstdio>`.

Next you are creating a pointer to an object and trying to push that pointer onto your stack. No need to make a pointer, just define the object directly.

Finally using `eingabe[0]` only gives you the first letter of the word stored in `eingabe`.

Try the following:

```
//#include <stdio.h> // not this in C++
#include <cstdio> // use this instead
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct adresse
{

    string info;
};

int main()
{

    string eingabe;
    stack<adresse> Stack1;

    cout << "Bitte Ausdruck eingeben: " << endl;
    getline(cin, eingabe);

    // no need to make pointers just use
    // adresse as if it were built in
    adresse temp;
    temp.info = eingabe; // [0] will only give you the first letter
    Stack1.push(temp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
adresse temp;
temp.info = eingabe;
Stack1.push(temp); // maybe `std::move(temp)` instead of `temp`
```

instead of the `new` and stuff you did with `temp`.  `new` is not required here.  `[0]` is not required.  Pointers are not required.

In general, `new` means "create a copy of this whose lifetime I will manage manually, and whose access is slower".  It returns a pointer to the thing you `new`ed.  If you don't need fine-grained control over the lifetime of what you are creating, create it on the stack instead.

In some modern C++ coding styles, all calls to `new` outside of specific low level resource management functions are discouraged (like `make_shared` or `make_unique` or `boost::variant` or the like).  But you still need to understand pointers.

You created a pointer to some data, and you tried to store it in a container that expects values of some data.  The container wanted a reference to an existing chunk of data which it would copy: you gave it a pointer to some data instead.  These are not the same type, so the compiler gave you an error saying there was no way to automatically convert from one type to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your stack to contain `adresse`s, but are trying to push the *address* of an `adresse`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to do what you are doing you would need a stack like so,

```
stack<adresse*> Stack1;
```

If you want to use your own stack then push it like so

```
Stack1.push(*temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing `Stack1.push(temp)`, `temp` is a `adresse *`, while `Stack1.push` expects an `adresse const &` argument.

This is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

To fix this issue, just do not store `temp` as a pointer to the object but rather directly as the object.